# React: using refs in a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

I'm new to React and I'm trying to figure out how to use Refs in my function component to get the width of a div. Some code demonstrating my confusion is below:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const eyes = useRef();

  function onMouseMoveFn(e) {
    const x = eyes.current.offsetX();
    const y = eyes.current.offsetY();
    console.log(x, y, eyes);
  }

  return (
    <div onMouseMove={onMouseMoveFn}>
      <div class="eyes" ref={eyes}>
        <div class="eye" />
        <div class="eye" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

A demo can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-perlman-zn0cj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

(when hovering your mouse over the eyes in the browser of the sandbox it should ideally result in the console displaying the x and y coordinates of the set of eyes but instead, it gives an error)

In React's documentation, it says "You can, however, use the ref attribute inside a function component as long as you refer to a DOM element or a class component" so I don't understand why the code above doesn't work.

Comment: Didn't you mean [`offsetLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft) / [`offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access offsets by using `getBoundingClientRect` function of current element, see the following code:

```
eyes.current.getBoundingClientRect().x
```

Comment: Also, you have issues in your codesandbox - rename `class` to `className` for `div` elements ;)